# Mac Default Python Path Change

Tags: python, linux, macos, path

Hi I have a Mac and happen to have many different flavors of Python installed everywhere.

right now when I opened up python in terminal, type in

```
which python
```

the return result is:

```
//anaconda/bin/python
```

I am wondering what should I do to change the default python to a python that I like, so next time when I do:

```
which python
```

the path should be:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
```

Thanks!

Comment: Add an alias to `.bash_profile` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`which` command uses the directories listed in `$PATH` to search for the first occurrence of a command. If you want to list all instances of executables, use -a option.

```
which python2.7
```

Output:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7
```

This will display symbolic link to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7`

to resolve symbolic link use

```
readlink $(which python2.7)
```

output:

```
../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
```

Comment: when I do which python2.7, I got: //anaconda/bin/python2.7 which is still not what I want.

Comment: @ParagBafna when I do 'which python', it still shows the previous path but readlink $(which python2.7) shows the path that I want my python to link to. So does it mean that the path has been updated?

Answer (score 2):

When you installed Anaconda it should have added a new item to your PATH variable, right at the front. You should see something like this in your *~/.bash_profile* file:

```
# added by Anaconda 1.8.0 installer
export PATH="//anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

You can remove these lines, reopen any terminal window you have and your default Python should have been restored.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a symbolic link

`ln -s /anaconda/bin/python /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7`