# AttributeError: 'ZAxis' object has no attribute '_set_scale' error indicates matplotlib libraries in many places?! How to fix?

Tags: python, matplotlib, osx-mavericks

I'm getting the following error message when I try to plot a set of points in 3d using matplotlib:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/r8t/summer-2014/diffusion-maps/diffusion1.py", line 55, in <module>
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/figure.py", line 789, in add_subplot
    a = subplot_class_factory(projection_class)(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/axes.py", line 8457, in __init__
    self._axes_class.__init__(self, fig, self.figbox, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 91, in __init__
    *args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/axes.py", line 463, in __init__
    self.cla()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 1040, in cla
    self.zaxis._set_scale('linear')
AttributeError: 'ZAxis' object has no attribute '_set_scale'
```

This seems to indicate that axes3d.p is in "/Library ... /axes3d.py", but self.cla() is in "/System/..."

I consulted [python: AttributeError: 'ZAxis' object has no attribute '_set_scale'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647836/python-attributeerror-zaxis-object-has-no-attribute-set-scale)
where the comment said there were two copies of the library, and the asker seemed to figure out how to fix it. Can someone tell me how to fix it?

I'm running OS X 10.9.3, and recently updated, although I'm not sure that's relevant.

I tried to pip uninstall matplotlib, but I think it only removed the folders in "/Library...". I also tried to pip install again, but afterward got the same result.

Thanks!!!
Bobby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working on mac os x 10.9.5.
I tried to solve this problem by specify the working path, but I failed.

Then I used brew to reinstall Python, and did following steps:

brew install python --framework --universal

cd /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions

sudo rm Current

sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current

Finally, I succeeded. I can plot 3D figures using matplotlib.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a dump of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647836/python-attributeerror-zaxis-object-has-no-attribute-set-scale) and the problem is related with the upgrade. The paths got messed up. If you see your output, one line says

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py"
```

And the line above says:

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/axes.py"
```

Some of those two Library folders is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I agree that your link to your previous post is the same problem, and I had viewed that before making this question.  But the question still remains- how do I fix it? I've looked in both the paths, and indeed python files are there- somehow I've got python files all over :p .  I'm thinking the best thing to do is delete it all, and do a fresh install of python and the modules I need. Is there a way to change the paths or something?

Comment: Check your PATH variable, the most probable thing is that the import order changed. Just put the python interpreter path you want to use first (or remove the one you don't want).

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538473/mac-default-python-path-change) I use 
'export PATH="//anaconda/bin:$PATH" '
How does this differ from importing sys, and amending the sys.path list?
Also, thanks!

Comment: @travelingbones if you import sys and use the sys.path, you will be still using the wrong python interpreter.

Comment: Ah, I see, so using a new sys.path() means the wrong python interpreter will have a new place to look for when I import things. I think I've got it! Thanks